# How to get to nested elements from the response from the server?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm getting a response from the server with a large nesting, and I can't display the second nesting with dynamic elements.
For example, like this - `Text('Child header name - ${catalogDrawer[index].one[index].name}'),`
won't work
however, if the index is replaced by a number from 0 to 1, then there will be no error - `Text('Child header name - ${catalogDrawer[index].one[0].name}'),`
Also, I can easily display first level data - `Text('Header name - ${catalogDrawer[index].name}'),`
But, everything that goes lower in nesting is a disaster. What do i do?

Here is the response from the server -

```
"categories": [
        {
            "name": "Dlya nego",
            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nego/",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "obyv",
                    "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nego/obuv/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Krossovki",
                            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nego/obuv/krossovki/",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "slancy",
                            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nego/obuv/slancy/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Kurtki",
                    "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nego/Kurtki/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "bombery",
                            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nego/Kurtki/bombery/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dlya nee",
            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nee/",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "obyv",
                    "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nee/obuv/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Krossovki",
                            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/dlya-nee/obuv/krossovki/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "deti",
            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/deti/",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "obuv",
                    "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/deti/obuv/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "krossovki",
                            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/deti/obuv/krossovki/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Sale",
            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/sale/",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "obuv",
                    "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/sale/obuv/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Krossovki",
                            "url": "https://dev.radiwear.com/api/v1/m/catalog/sale/obuv/krossovki/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Here is my entity -

```
class CatalogDrawerEntity extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final String url;
  final List<OneChildren> one;
  const CatalogDrawerEntity ({
    required this.name,
    required this.url,
    required this.one
});
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [name, url, one];
}

class OneChildren {
 final String name;
 final String url;
 final List<TwoChildren> two;

 const OneChildren({
   required this.name,
   required this.url,
   required this.two
});
}

class TwoChildren {
  final String name;
  final String url;
  TwoChildren({
    required this.name,
    required this.url
});
}
```

Here is my model -

```
class CatalogDrawerModel extends CatalogDrawerEntity {
  const CatalogDrawerModel({
    required name,
    required url,
    required one
}) : super (
    name: name,
    url: url,
    one: one
  );

  factory CatalogDrawerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CatalogDrawerModel(
        name: json['name'],
        url: json['url'],
        one: json['children'] != null
        ? (json['children'] as List<dynamic>).map((json) => OneModel.fromJson(json)).toList()
            : null
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'url': url,
      'children': one
    };
  }
}
```

And

```
class OneModel extends OneChildren{
  OneModel({name, url, two}) : super (name: name, url: url, two: two);

  factory OneModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return OneModel(
      name: json['name'],
      url: json['url'],
      two: json['children'] != null
        ? (json['children'] as List<dynamic>).map((json) => TwoModel.fromJson(json)).toList()
          : null
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'url': url,
      'two': two
    };
  }
}

class TwoModel extends TwoChildren{
  TwoModel({name, url}) : super (name: name, url: url);

  factory TwoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TwoModel(
      name: json['name'],
      url: json['url']
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'url': url
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the processing of data from the server -

```
Future<List<CatalogDrawerModel>> getAllCatalogDrawer() async {
    final response = await client.get(
      Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.home),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'applications/json'}
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      List catalogDrawer = json.decode(response.body)['categories'];
      return catalogDrawer.map((data) => CatalogDrawerModel.fromJson(data)).toList();
      // final catalogDrawer= json.decode(response.body);
      // print('Данные для карточек - $catalogDrawer');
      // return (catalogDrawer['categories'] as List).map((e) => CatalogDrawerModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }
```

Comment: could you add the way you are showing theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are parsing it is correct but the way you are showing it is wrong, you can't use same index of `catalogDrawer` for `one`, try this:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var one = catalogDrawer[index].one;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                var two = one[i].two;

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, ii) {
                    return Text('Child header name -  ${two[ii].name}');
                  },
                  itemCount: two.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                );
              },
              itemCount: one.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
            );
          },
          itemCount: checkboxes.length,
        )
```

Comment: up to the second nesting it worked, but can you suggest how to get to the third one?

Comment: exactly like second one, check out my update.

Comment: I had one mistake, check out again.

Comment: check is it correct? https://dpaste.org/4ktCB